# Knockoff xbox 360 controller wireless adapter limited to two controllers rather than four in windows 10

Tags: xbox360, wireless-adapter, controller

So I've had this adapter for a long time; since my computer still ran windows 7, and it used to be capable of connecting four controllers but for some reason it recently has only been able to connect two controllers instead. I've tried reinstalling the driver and selecting every version available with windows 10 but nothing I try seems to work. The hardware ID of the device as shown in device manager is: VID_045E&PID_0291. Any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps Microsoft updated their software in a way that breaks 4 controller compatibility with that particular device.